# tcp_probe fields

Tags: networking, tcp

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS with the custom kernel provided here: https://github.com/multipath-tcp/mptcp

The kernel version is 4.4.70 enabled with multipath TCP. I ran tcp_probe to look at the window sizes during a 10 second iperf3 session with 2 subflows. The linux tcp testing documentation here: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/tcp_testing does not really describe the fields clearly. Is there a better or a more recent documentation for tcp_probe.

I am interested in 2 things:

1. To understand the difference between congestion window (field 7) and sender window (field 9) as mentioned in the above documentation. Isn't the sender window the same as the congestion window (unless the receiver advertises a size smaller than the congestion window)?
2. In what units are the 7th and 9th fields logged? These fields correspond to the cwnd and sender window.